# Get Image from local directory using Swing?

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource

I trying to load image from local directory into ImageIcon(URL).This images files access from .jar file.The jar file name is swingex.jar.The project structure like

```
F:/>SwingExample
         |
         |___src
         |
         |___build.xml
         |
         |___lib
               |
               |___swingsex.jar(generated through build.xml file)
         |
         |__resource
                   |
                   |_____images
                            |
                            |___logo1.png
```

How to read logo1.png file?

I'm trying to like this

1. `file:///f://resources//images//processedimages//` returns null
2. `ClassLoader.getSystemResource("resources/images/processedimages/");` returns null

**Update :-**
             Still i have problem.because  i created jar file on SwingExample and excludes the resource/images directory .When run the jar file its not recognized the resource/images folder.But i ran the SwingExample Project through eclipse it working fine.The code is

> ```
> File directory = new File (".");
> Image img = null;
> String path="";
> URL url=null;
> try {
>   path=directory.getCanonicalPath()+"/resources/images/logo1.png";
>                img = ImageIO.read(new File(getDefaultImageUploadPath());
>
> } catch (IOException e) {
>   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>   e.printStackTrace();
> }
>         return new ImageIcon(img);
> ```

Comment: Your structure and attempts do not match.

Comment: `ClassLoader.getSystemResource("resources/images/processedimages/");`  Try instead something like: `this.getClass().getResource("/resources/images/logo1.png");`

Answer (score 3):

```
URL imgURL =
   new File( "F:/SwingExample/resource/images/logo1.png" ).toURI().toURL();
```

But I suggest to put resource into src.

If resource is in src, you may access them by class loader easily.

```
getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "resource/images/logo1.png" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the execution context of your application, you could use a relative path instead

```
URL imgURL = new File( "resource/images/logo1.png" ).toURI().toURL();
```

Or

```
URL imgURL = new File( "../resource/images/logo1.png" ).toURI().toURL();
```

Might work, but Aubin is correct, it would be easier to embed the image within your application and access via the class loader context

Answer (score 0):

For java projects, default directory always starts from src. Your code will work fine only if you organize resource in below way.... :)

```
SwingExample
         |
         |___src
         |    |
         |    |_____resource
         |          |
         |          |_____images
         |                   |
         |                   |___logo1.png
         |___build.xml
         |
         |___lib
               |
               |___swingsex.jar(generated through build.xml file)
```

This time `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "/resource/images/logo1.png" );` wont return null.