# Using jWindow as splash screen which shows good but image doesn't paint ... just blank jWindow opened...any thoughts?

Tags: java, jwindow

1. jWindow opened for 2 seconds but image doesn't paint... any thoughts?
2. image file is in the same folder as class file...

```
public class CreateSplashScreen extends JWindow {
    JWindow jw = new JWindow();
    Image scImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("testImage.png");
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(scImage);
    public CreateSplashScreen() {
        try {
            jw.setSize(700, 500);
            jw.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jw.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
       super.paint(g);
       g.drawImage(scImage, 0, 0, jw);
    }

    public void CloseSplashScreen() {
        jw.setVisible(false);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreateSplashScreen sp = new CreateSplashScreen();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CreateSplashScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        sp.CloseSplashScreen();
    }
    
}
```

1. jWindow opened for 2 seconds but image doesn't paint... any thoughts?
2. image file is in the same folder as class file...

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating an internal `JWindow` when your class `CreateSplashScreen` already extends `JWindow`?
There is no need of it. You are messing with your program.

***How?***
You are actually viewing the inner `JWindow` by `jw.setVisible(true);` but you are painting the image in the `CreateSplashScreen`'s `JWindow.

Try this code :

```
public class CreateSplashScreen extends JWindow 
{
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/createsplashscreen/testImage.png"));
    
    public CreateSplashScreen() {
     setSize(700, 500);
     setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
     super.paint(g);
     g.drawImage(i.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void CloseSplashScreen() {
     setVisible(false);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreateSplashScreen sp = new CreateSplashScreen();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            
        }
        sp.CloseSplashScreen();
    }    
}
```

**Note:** I do not know about your method to fetch image resource from the source folder.

**Edit:** Assuming that the name of the package containing your class `CreateSplashScreen` is `createsplashscreen`, make sure that the image `testImage.png` is present in the `createsplashscreen` package of your project.

Comment: Do I need method to fetch image from folder?

Comment: Had no idea about that ... maybe that's why it didn't paint?    Could you give me some hint if you can?

Comment: @Hana *Do I need method to fetch image from folder?* - I said I do not know about your method. It might work. Or it might not. If it doesn't, try reading this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845231/how-to-correctly-get-image-from-resources-folder-in-netbeans

Comment: @Hana I have updated the code in the answer and it works. Try it.

Comment: @Hana An advice : Please learn more about how to include resources in your project folder and how to fetch those resources from your package folder. This is where you can start from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928116/how-to-set-image-on-jlabel-from-project-folder and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819454/get-image-from-local-directory-using-swing?rq=1

Comment: Thank you Peter ... tried your code but ended up with java.lang.NullPointException.  path is "/name of package/imagefile"     also made  Resources folder  under src package folder and "/Resources/image file" but didn't work either .... always end up with NullPointException error.... out of options now. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Hana Can you edit the question and add a screenshot of your project structure showing the location of your image file and `CreateSplashScreen` class? Also, please add your current code, in which you are getting a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Like you said image file is inside of package folder, somehow I add a line in manifest. mf file as "SplashScreen-Image: /packagename/imagefile" and that solved problem          Will add screen shot when I get home for any possible issue. Thanks Peter

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screen shot of file structure]

@Peter
For error code, I deleted one line that I added in mamifest.mf file and build a program...
This time, didn't give me an error, weird...
I was following error code when I got it and it led me to something like "CLASSPATH" section of application generated code... sorry I can't remember exactly
Really appreciate Peter for your help.
Wish you luck...